# Storing selected language in localStorage

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am making a website with the option to change languages. Every time when you refresh the page though, the language you selected returns to the original language.
The code below shows the html and JavaScript code for how this function works:

```js
const langEl = [...document.querySelectorAll(".lang")];
const textEl = document.querySelector(".text");

let chosenLanguage = 'NL';

langEl.forEach((el) => {
  el.addEventListener("click", () => {
    langEl.map(item => item.classList.contains("active") ? item.classList.remove("active") : false);
    el.classList.add("active");
    chosenLanguage = el.innerText;

    const attr = el.getAttribute("language");

    textEl.textContent = data[attr].text;
  });
});

var data = {
  dutch: {
    text: "test test"
  },
  english: {
    text: "test test"
  },
  spanish: {
    text: "prueba prueba"
  },
  indonesian: {
    text: "tes tes"
  }
};
```

```css
:root {
  --secondary-color: #4978ff;
}

.language {
  background: #141414;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 60px 0 50px;
}

.language a {
  margin: 0;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 0 15px;
  font-weight: bold;
  background: #555656;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.language a.active {
  background: var(--secondary-color);
}
```

```html
<p class="text">test test</p>

<div class="language">
  <div class="langWrap">
    <a href="#" language='dutch' class="lang active">NL</a>
    <a href="#" language='english' class="lang">EN</a>
    <a href="#" language='spanish' class="lang">ES</a>
    <a href="#" language='indonesian' class="lang">ID</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

I was wondering if it was possible to store the chose language in the localStorage so that it stays the same after you refresh the page?

Comment: Have you tried using local storage see eg https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API/Using_the_Web_Storage_API

Comment: @AHaworth I did, but i don’t quite understand how it works for this specific bit of code. I have made other functions that are being stored in localhost that don’t have any problems. This one just doesn’t seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already noted - use `localStorage`. Gave you a working example, but it won't work on stackoverflow.com because of `allow-same-origin`:

```js
const langEls = document.querySelectorAll('.lang');
const textEl = document.querySelector('.text');

const chosenLanguage = localStorage.getItem('lang') || 'nl';
document.querySelector(`.language [data-lang="${chosenLanguage}"]`).classList.add('active')

const i18n = {
  nl: {
    text: 'nl'
  },
  en: {
    text: 'en'
  },
  es: {
    text: 'es'
  },
  id: {
    text: 'id'
  }
};

textEl.textContent = i18n[chosenLanguage].text;

langEls.forEach(el => {
  el.addEventListener('click', () => {
     const lang = el.dataset.lang;
    langEls.forEach(langEl => langEl.classList.remove('active'));
    el.classList.add('active');
    textEl.textContent = i18n[lang].text;
     localStorage.setItem('lang', lang);
  });
});
```

```css
:root {
  --secondary-color: #4978ff;
}

.language {
  background: #141414;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 60px 0 50px;
}

.language a {
  margin: 0;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 0 15px;
  font-weight: bold;
  background: #555656;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.language a.active {
  background: var(--secondary-color);
}
```

```html
<p class="text"></p>

<div class="language">
  <div class="langWrap">
    <a href="#" data-lang="nl" class="lang">NL</a>
    <a href="#" data-lang="en" class="lang">EN</a>
    <a href="#" data-lang="es" class="lang">ES</a>
    <a href="#" data-lang="id" class="lang">ID</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It works! Thank you very much, me and my friend where stuck on this for hours XD